# AS2: class not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

here is my class so far:

```
 class com.RCN.Menu.Menu extends MovieClip {

    public var title:String;
    public var menuItems:Array;
    public var titleField:MovieClip;

    public function Menu(title:String, menuItems:Array, menuActions:Array) {
        this.titleField = createTitleBar(title);
    }

    public function createTitleBar(title:String) {
        var titleBar = createEmptyMovieClip("titleBar", 1);
            var titleText = createTextField("titleText", this.getNextHighestDepth(), 10, 10, 100, 100);
            titleText.text = title;
            titleText.autoSize = true;
            titleText.multiline = false;
            titleText.wordWrap = false;
            titleText.border = true;
            titleText.background = 0xffffff;
            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Arial";
            format.size = 14.5;
            format.bold = true;
            format.align = "left";
            titleText.setTextFormat(format);
            return titleBar;
    }
}
```

Yet in my SWF when I run the following code I get undefined, can anyone see why? (new to classes)

```
import com.RCN.Menu.Menu;

var Accountability:Menu = new Menu("hello",[a,b,c,d]);
trace(Accountability.titleField);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to createEmptyMovieClip is failing because there is no stage to create a movieclip on.  Consider this simple example of how to do this without attaching your class to a library item:

Class:

```
class MyMenu extends MovieClip {

    public var titleField:MovieClip;

    public function MyMenu($target:MovieClip) {
        this.titleField = createTitleBar($target);
    }

    public function createTitleBar($target:MovieClip):MovieClip {
        var titleBar = $target.createEmptyMovieClip("titleBar", 1);
        return titleBar;
    }
}
```

IDE:

```
import MyMenu;
var menu:MyMenu = new MyMenu(this);
trace(menu.titleField);
```